# Heroku is not allowing me to use the transformers module in Python

Tags: python, heroku

I am installing `transformers` on Heroku. Why am I getting this error?

```py
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/transformers/

GitHub: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/

Docs: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transformers` currently does not support the latest version of Python (`3.10`) and hence, you will have to switch to an old version that is available on Heroku. The following versions are recommended:

- `python-3.9.10`
- `python-3.8.12`
- `python-3.7.12`

Try editing your `runtime.txt` file to one of the above versions and you should not get that error.